# Eclipse not connecting to xdebug

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I am unable to connect to xdebug from eclipse. Following is my xdebug config in php.ini

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php56-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_port=10000
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = On
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

And i am getting following log in xdebug.log

```
Log opened at 2016-11-08 11:55:46
I: Checking remote connect back address.
I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
I: Checking header 'REMOTE_ADDR'.
I: Remote address found, connecting to 127.0.0.1:10000.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///Library/WebServer/Documents/akeneo/pim-community-standard/web/app.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="5.6.24" protocol_version="1.0" appid="6191" idekey="ECLIPSE_DBGP"><engine version="2.4.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2016 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- feature_set -i 127 -n show_hidden -v 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="127" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 128 -n max_depth -v 3
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="128" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 129 -n max_children -v 51
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="129" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

<- feature_set -i 130 -n max_data -v 1024
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="130" feature="max_data" success="1"></response>

<- feature_get -i 131 -n encoding
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="131" feature_name="encoding" supported="1"><![CDATA[iso-8859-1]]></response>

<- feature_get -i 132 -n supports_async
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_get" transaction_id="132" feature_name="supports_async" supported="1"><![CDATA[0]]></response>

<- stdout -i 133 -c 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="133" success="1"></response>

<- stderr -i 134 -c 1
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stderr" transaction_id="134" success="0"></response>

<- step_into -i 135
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="126" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2016-11-08 11:55:46
```

I also have a big stream of data after this.

Eclipse is showing PHP Application (Waiting....)

What could be wrong here.

Comment: seems like this is an issue with wrong encoding, eclipse can't handle the encoded response.